# Flutter flutter_native_admob package failing to load add

Tags: android, flutter, admob, native

I'm trying to display my admob ads in my app natively with the flutter_native_admob package but for some reason the test ad never loads.

I get the following errors.

```
I/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  ( 6263): uid=10091(com.example.XXXXXXXXapp) identical 1 line
I/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/DynamiteModule( 6263): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
I/DynamiteModule( 6263): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
D/DynamitePackage( 6263): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
D/DynamitePackage( 6263): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdLoaderBuilderCreatorImpl
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 6263): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/Ads     ( 6263): This request is sent from a test device.
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/DynamiteModule( 6263): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21400
I/DynamiteModule( 6263): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21400
I/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/WebViewFactory( 6263): Loading com.android.chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (code 349710067)
I/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Background concurrent copying GC freed 32981(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 16(340KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 81.243ms total 180.818ms
E/FA      ( 6263): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
I/FA      ( 6263): App measurement is starting up, version: 18102
I/FA      ( 6263): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA      ( 6263): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
I/FA      ( 6263):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.XXXXXXXXapp
E/FA      ( 6263): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https://goo(.)gl/NAOOOI
E/FA      ( 6263): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
I/cr_LibraryLoader( 6263): Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 6211-6213)
I/chromium( 6263): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader( 6263): Expected native library version number "69.0.3497.100", actual native library version number "69.0.3497.100"
E/cr_VariationsUtils( 6263): Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXXapp/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXXapp/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
W/cr_ChildProcLH( 6263): Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
I/cr_BrowserStartup( 6263): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker;->logEvent(Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionStarted(I)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(II)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionModified(IILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextSelection;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
W/ple.XXXXXXXXap( 6263): Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(IIILandroid/view/textclassifier/TextClassification;)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent; (light greylist, reflection)
D/        ( 6263): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x71de949fcf60, tid 6511
W/cr_media( 6263): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
E/chromium( 6263): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
D/EGL_emulation( 6263): eglCreateContext: 0x71de947c2d60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 6263): eglMakeCurrent: 0x71de947c2d60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x71de919c6660)
I/Choreographer( 6263): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/VideoCapabilities( 6263): Unrecognized profile 4 for video/hevc
I/VideoCapabilities( 6263): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
W/cr_MediaCodecUtil( 6263): HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
W/cr_CrashFileManager( 6263): /data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXXapp/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
I/System.out( 6263): onAdFailedToLoad errorCode = 0
I/Ads     ( 6263): Ad failed to load : 0
E/chromium( 6263): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
D/EGL_emulation( 6263): eglCreateContext: 0x71de9b1ded80: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 6263): eglMakeCurrent: 0x71de9b1ded80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x71de919c6660)
```

I already added the

```xml
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-XXX~YYYY"/>
```

inside my application tag.

And I made sure to include the `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` dependency and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my build.gradle.  I'm not quite sure how to resolve this.

Comment: facing same problem.